# Does Redux Saga has any way to wait for some action to be dispatched but till certain time?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

In our project we have below scenario:

1. Send WebSocket message
2. Wait till certain time(3seconds) for acknowledgement response
3. If acknowledgement not received in 3 seconds then retry request
   NOTE: once Acknowledgement received, we are able to trigger Redux Saga action.

So looking for some way where we can wait for Redux action but till certain time?

Something like

> take(ActionName, 3000)

Comment: Sounds like a `race()` call.  Very similar to their [retry recipe](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/recipes/#retrying-xhr-calls).

Comment: Since redux-saga v1 there is also the `retry` effect https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#retrymaxtries-delay-fn-args

Comment: Thanks, ```race()``` did trick for me.